# Colleges that showcase their calculus material online

Tags: calculus

Since I will be creating a calculus course, I am hoping to find calculus material used in the best colleges across the globe as a reference. Lecture notes and exercise sheets are highly appreciated.

Do you know any college that showcases their course?

Comment: Calculus textbooks are now obsolete?

Comment: my own: http://www.lightandmatter.com/fund/

Comment: FWIW, my automated tutorials for mathematics can be used as a supplement: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MIT offers a lot of their class materials online through their [**OpenCourseWare initiative**](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm).

You can find a list of their calculus classes [**here**](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=mathematics&subcat=calculus).

Answer (score 1):

There are several "free" (or very cheap) "textbook" initiatives, like [Trillia](http://trillia.com), William Chen has a set of [lecture notes](https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/Chen-notes/ln.html) that I like a lot, asking Google for "free mathematics textbooks" gives many hits. Searching for specific topics will net you lots of more or less formal notes, slides, webpages for courses (often with homework and exams and solutions).

Answer (score 1):

As most colleges and universities are moving their online [open course ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCourseWare) to hosting sites such as [edX](https://www.edx.org/) and [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) I would search their catalogs.

Search results for calculus
 - [edX](https://www.edx.org/course?search_query=calculus)
 - [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?languages=en&query=calculus)

TL;DR

To find sites that host open and free online courses check the list of [notable providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course#Notable_providers) in the [Massive open online course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) Wikipedia article